# How to interpret/do a correlation/regression analysis if underlying relation has to be asymptotic?

Tags: regression, correlation, nonlinear-regression

I want to do a correlation/regression analysis of a dependent and an independet variable.

I've got the following problem:
I want to analyze how the number of produced goods affects the price.
At the beginning with a raising number of produced goods the price drops quite fast but then it flattens out.
From the theory of the problem I'd say that the realtion is asymptotic (see drawing).

Somehow I can't really find a way on how to do a correlation/regression analysis on asymptotic data though.
Shouldnt be this relation of variables be quite common?

Hope that someone could help me..

Thanks guys

[image]

Comment: In working with numeric data for regression and correlation computation, full asymptotic analysis is not possible as in analytical asymptotics. One could talk about sample size limits.

Comment: @mehmet suzen which way would you suggest to analyze data like in the above graph then?

Comment: This look like a [power-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law). One could use such analysis.

Answer (score 0):

One would need to do [power law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) analysis. See the seminal paper, [Power-law distributions in empirical data](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062). There is an R package [poweRlaw](https://github.com/csgillespie/poweRlaw) to help in this direction.

**Edit**: Nice suggestion from @whuber, due to frequency of posts in CV, [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) can also be used to model such data. However, intrinsically different than power laws, see discussion [Difference between power law distribution and exponential decay](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164436/difference-between-power-law-distribution-and-exponential-decay)

Comment: What about this question suggests a power law?  That rules out the much commoner case of exponential decay, for instance.

Comment: @whuber 
Why do you think exponential decay is much more common in economics?

Comment: I didn't write that and don't think that.  My opinion about "much commoner" is based on the frequencies of posts here on CV.

Comment: @whuber Ok. Got it. I though you were referring to economics as OP was about economic variable. Edited to accommodate your input. Edit my answer further, if you have further recommendation or link to other questions from your experience.

Comment: I appreciate your gracious reply. This question is broader than it may look, because it requires extensive analysis for a good solution.  Keywords (useful for searches on this site) include data visualization; data transformation; and nonlinear regression.  The idea is to perform an analysis (or, even better, invoke economic theory!) to identify likely functional forms of the relationship and to determine the principal stochastic features of the data (their errors and correlations, usually) and only then to identify a suitable regression procedure.